# How to create URL from string containing Turkish chars (çıüöğ) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, utf-8, alamofire

I'm creating an app for my clients Wordpress website. When he uploads an asset he sometimes uses Turkish chars on it; for example:

`https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Samsun-Büyük-güne-hazır.jpg`

`URL.init(string:)` does not take this as a valid URL.

So how can I handle this situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let string = "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Samsun-Büyük-güne-hazır.jpg".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)
let url = URL(string: string!)
```

Comment: I tried every one of URLEncoding types, it looks like forgot this one. Thank you.